# Mining Block header bit reversing

Tags: mining-pools, hash, python, block-header, merkle-tree

While trying to understand the mining process and checking in python..... i am puzzled with which info from/to pool are in Little Endian, which one needs reversing in building the block header + hashing and which one not. ??

For example ... Let's start with connecting to solo.ckpool.org
response to mining.authorize gives me ..... job_id,prevhash,coinb1,coinb2,merkle_branch,version,nbits,ntime,clean_jobs =

```
{'id': None, 'method': 'mining.notify', 'params': ['59bc8dfc0000029f',
        '0eba48f47bc0ab4bb35b230849868bf1d79aeb19006eed460000000000000000',
        '01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff35039a6807000404d5bc5904fc873d140c',
        '0a636b706f6f6c112f736f6c6f2e636b706f6f6c2e6f72672fffffffff03c4626c4e000000001976a914fc6123f4bfd3a840b4387ab90e9801e98fb17cf888acb1caca00000000001976a914f4cbe6c6bb3a8535c963169c22963d3a20e7686988ac0000000000000000266a24aa21a9edab3b87f3963e55a23f3cea5e4435bf6637328fd5e329bb8fdac7d31c3a01d26200000000',
        ['c251d18568d2cdb07c376d5f3304a2161e3d09d289d1a7e53737199171d73ae6',
         '4f9bcac3ec00fc8238db04b7758a1b673bdf38b93e48159678b60b51517dd563',
         '2aadad2c9c8e6df5c71264524b090cdf89830f12949527f7872c243bc1dc552c',
         '8c5edf39c0d85c9853308eef3ce6f9b71c8d6584ca4120d411bc75987bb2f254',
         '48751c2ae0ddc05f5d504a3d6039e7d5afb3d5f2a6aaac93bd5822e5f8efc328',
         '3e9b5c6b986c2ddc09bf8604eb2bd2a3b49b46f11042c282331a206dadb4296e',
         'c65f502b11b325abc0fac847e8fc5cd300169160e7244b29dd5acc3d0e4b8605',
         'afe7d2287020c4291f609a772adbeafc952a8de0ced38a7346acb6c7103bec6d',
         '0caa545ae63de39d47baea100ea15a18061235d7e1a372fbca88edf9ca5ac797',
         'c5bfff15b4dd64e7faac98f1bba118fb11990e4ff146cb45c7f4af6b93e2ea03',
         'a8805201e8152c1f5835c9aa024752fb34aeb7fa55dd3af0ae6109918f328dbb'],
        '20000000',
        '1801310b',
        '59bcd504',
        True]}
```

Based on the pool response....I can build the coinbase just by

```
coinbase = coinb1 + extranonce1 + extranonce2 + coinb2 
coinbase_hash_bin = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(coinbase)).digest()).digest()
```

and same to include in merkle tree with hashing to get merkle_root. **I am not sure if i need to reverse the bits here ?**

But to build a block header ... should i do this..

```
header = version + prevhash + merkle_root + ntime + nbits + nonce
```

or this..

```
header = binascii.hexlify(binascii.unhexlify(version)[::-1]).decode('utf-8') + \
prevhash + \
merkle_root + \
binascii.hexlify(binascii.unhexlify(ntime)[::-1]).decode('utf-8') + \
binascii.hexlify(binascii.unhexlify(nbits)[::-1]).decode('utf-8') + \
binascii.hexlify(binascii.unhexlify(nonce)[::-1]).decode('utf-8')
```

blockheader:000000200eba48f47bc0ab4bb35b230849868bf1d79aeb19006eed460000000000000000fb68998fe1dd4cc22fa1225c2592c27df5331d40d9b33ffce99b26c0aead8ef404d5bc590b3101181e3eef8c

Can someone please post an example of a recent BLOCK HEADER ... **i think i m doing something wrong !**

I am comparing this hash

```
hash = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(header)).digest()).digest()[::-1]
```

with the target "000000000001310b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look at this block, because it only has one transaction (the coinbase): [000000000000000000eb2d0ed97a7b2cff7f1408417dca83908004beb6fd9b95](https://blockchain.info/block/000000000000000000eb2d0ed97a7b2cff7f1408417dca83908004beb6fd9b95)

Let's grab the raw hex data:

> 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

There are 6 things which make up the block header:

1. First we have the version (4 bytes), `00000020`, which is reversed bytes of `0x20000000`.
2. Then we have the previous block hash (32 bytes), also in reversed byte order, `53f7ebc735f54ac8d4ebcc1eeb3d3bdea89603bdd27431000000000000000000` which is [this block](https://blockchain.info/block/0000000000000000003174d2bd0396a8de3b3deb1eccebd4c84af535c7ebf753).
3. Next we have the merkle root of the transactions (32 bytes), in reverse byte order, `ff964ec70ea5a5356a04fdb044ca6c59ffda2dd6be02c63d9ea58fb6d46e0199`. Because there is only one transaction, the coinbase transaction, the merkle root is just equal to [that transactions](https://blockchain.info/tx/99016ed4b68fa59e3dc602bed62ddaff596cca44b0fd046a35a5a50ec74e96ff) txid.
4. Then we have the time stamp (4 bytes), in reverse byte order, `1a22bb59` which is `0x59bb221a` in hex or `1505436186` in decimal.
5. Then we have the reversed bytes of the 'bits' field (4 bytes), `0b310118` which is `0x1801310b`
6. And then the nonce (4 bytes), `f6df26f8` which is `0xf826dff6`

Then after the header, we have the byte `01` which means there is one transaction, which follows. That one transaction is just the encoded coinbase transaction, as you can see [here](https://blockchain.info/rawtx/99016ed4b68fa59e3dc602bed62ddaff596cca44b0fd046a35a5a50ec74e96ff?format=hex).

Of course, only the block header needs to be hashed, not the transactions too.

Comment: This is Awesome !! Thanks... All is very much clear now.. except the merkle root. binascii.hexlify(hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify('0100000000010100000000..........4e8cf90120000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')).digest()).digest()) This gives me "cb7ac0ad06517d90cd5a936aebb8b32205fefec268ac6970c04b528313f3ce26" and not "99016ed4b68fa59e3dc602bed62ddaff596cca44b0fd046a35a5a50ec74e96ff"

Comment: That's a witness transaction, so you have to modify it a bit before hashing it to find the txid (you currently found the wtxid). But that's a separate question , remember to accept my answer to your question if it satisfies you btw :)

Comment: Yes your answer is perfect, what i was looking for.

Comment: So everything in the submitted header of the block is byte-reversed of actual value?  In other words if you want to know the version from the block header, byte-reverse it, and you get the value.  This design is so unnecessarily confusing.

Answer (score 0):

MeshCollider's answer is awesome. I want to add a note. Why do the previous block header hash and merkle root hash need to reverse bytes? And why other fields doesn't need it?

Actually, if you want any transaction's hash, you need to double-sha256 hash. So, the point is: if some data need sha256 digest, and digest stores in the computer is little-endian, some case need to transform to big int in big-endian, so reverse the bytes. And you get the double-sha256 hash in bitcoin. In some case, the big-endian is necessary. e.g. big-int(block-header-hash) < Mining Target?

If you need transaction hash, the result is big-endian too.

For example, a raw transaction hex is:

`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`

then, you need transaction hash:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> d = '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'
>>> hashlib.sha256(bytes.fromhex(d)).hexdigest()
'240cf324ec3cf59609733e2a45e1408673306be8dcd4caf3067aa9355a0269e3'
>>> hashlib.sha256(bytes.fromhex('240cf324ec3cf59609733e2a45e1408673306be8dcd4caf3067aa9355a0269e3')).hexdigest()
'169e1e83e930853391bc6f35f605c6754cfead57cf8387639d3b4096c54f18f4'
```

`169e1e83e930853391bc6f35f605c6754cfead57cf8387639d3b4096c54f18f4` is little-endian hash, in the bitcoin, all the double-sha256 hash is big-endian.

In fact, this transaction's identifier is big-endian hash: `f4184fc596403b9d638783cf57adfe4c75c605f6356fbc91338530e9831e9e16`.

When you need to find some info about this transaction, you need input the big-endian hash: 
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/f4184fc596403b9d638783cf57adfe4c75c605f6356fbc91338530e9831e9e16

and little-endian hash you can find nothing.

Did you get it?

- previous block header hash need to reverse bytes, because bitcoin need big-endian.
- current block header hash need to reverse bytes, because bitcoin need big-endian.
- transaction hash need to reverse bytes, because bitcoin need big-endian.
- merkle root hash need to reverse bytes, because bitcoin need big-endian.

OMG! why? I found bitcoin core developer didn't know the reason.

> Due to historical accident, the tx and block hashes that bitcoin core uses are byte-reversed. I'm not entirely sure why. May be something like using openssl bignum to store hashes or something like that, then printing them as a number.
>
> ref: http://learnmeabitcoin.com/glossary/txid

Comment: There would be no need to check big/little endianes and do byte reversing if all data was stored as bytes instead of some as uint32.  For example getblocktemplate provides the bits field as a hexadecimal string, they could have done the same for version, curtime/ntime.  This design lacks simplicity and is unnecessarily twisted. It's stupid.  Can't believe bitcoin is worth anything.